# Access video in assets folder to play in Android VideoView

Tags: android, uri, android-videoview, assets

I have already read through the ton of answers about how to play the video from the raw/res folder referenced via the generated R.java class.

However, this is not what I want to do.

I am generating both the code for the application as well as the video files in the assets folder, so they can't be accessed via the static R.java class.

I am aware of the AssetManager and how to open an InputStream on the file, but the VideoView doesn't take an InputStream but a Uri.

So the question is how to either obtain an Uri from the InputStream/AssetManager or how to generate an Uri based on the filename of the file in the assets folder.

Comment: I would also love to know how to do this, and know exactly where you are coming from - did you ever find a way?

Answer (score -3):

```
Create One Folder in Res give name "raw" paste your all video you will use now   following code.

String strvideo = "android.resource://" + getPackageName().toString() + "/" +R.raw.videname;


videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    // videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
    // + getPackageName().toString() + "/"
    // + R.raw.simple_full_body_workout));

    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(strvideo );
```

Comment: As I have stated in the first sentence of my question, this is NOT what I want to do. I know how to play videos from the res/raw folder as this has been answered a couple of times here on SO. If you know how to playback videos from the assets folder however, I would really appreciate your help!